# How to bind socket to local address?

Tags: python, sockets, networking, ip

I searched a lot but was unable to find how I can bind a socket to local host address 192.168.1.6.

I tried

```
host = "192.168.1.6"
port = 1337
s.bind((host,port))
```

but it is giving the error

```
socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed
```

Here's my full code:

EDIT :-
server

```
import socket

def function(c):
    c.send('HTTP/1.0 200 OK\n'.encode())
    c.send('Content-Type: text/html\n'.encode())
    c.send("""<html> 
              <body>
              <h1> Hello World </h1> this is my server! 
              </body> 
              </html>""".encode())


with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect(("122.168.223.131", 80))
    host = s.getsockname()[0]
    print(host)
port = 1337
s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)
c, (client_host, client_port) = s.accept()
c.recv(1000)
print('Got connection from', client_host, client_port)
function(c)
```

client :-

```
from socket import *

host = gethostbyaddr('192.168.1.6')
print()
host_name = host[0]
port = 1337
print(host)
print(host_name)
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host_name, port))
```

the address in line 3 '192.168.1.6' is what I am getting by printing host in server program

Comment: Your second question is answered in the [help]. If you need clarification, ask in [meta]

Comment: IP `"192.168.1.6"` has to be IP of network card in computer on which you run this program. It can't be IP of other computer.

Comment: Also, `AF_INET6` has to use an IPv6 address. Use `AF_INET` for IPv4.

Comment: You don't bind addresses to sockets, you bind sockets to addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "getaddrinfo failed" error probably means that IP address might not be the address to your computer on the local network.
Try this

```
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect(("8.8.8.8", 80))
    host = s.getsockname()[0]
port = 1337

s = socket.socket()
s.bind((host, port))
```

Comment: thank you ... I have successfully created server using your code ... can you please give me the code for client program...I tried but I am getting error socket.gaierror: [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed....
i am able to access it through browser  using link 192.168.1.6:1337/index.html

Comment: If this solution worked for you, then you're most likely getting the IP address wrong. Are you on Windows or Linux?

Comment: You could probably add "print host" to the server code temporarily to what address the code is retrieving and know for sure if you're getting it right.

Comment: I am using print host while creating server... and using same in client... more I am using same ip to access through browser which is successful... (I am on windows)

Comment: And you're sure you're using the "s.accept()" function on the server side?

Comment: I have posted my edited code in the question above.
(thanks for the time...appreciate your help)

Comment: I can't guarantee that this will fix the issue (to be honest I have yet to figure out what's causing your error)
But try this in the client's code:

s = socket.create_connection((hostIP, port))

Comment: As opposed to the two lines of code:   s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM), 
 s.connect((host_name, port))

Comment: my god... It worked... I was studying this through a book and it told me use socket.connect((host,port)) command .... THANK YOU AGAIN

Comment: Perfect! Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do it like this:

```
import socket
host = "...."
port = ...
with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((host,port))
```